# C read multiple words/arguments with space from console

Tags: c

Hi I am new to C and I want the user to type something like `inspect 2` to show a value of an array at position 2 in that example.

I cant get it to work

```
    char input[20];
    scanf("%s", input);

    if (strcmp(strtok(input, " "), "inspect") == 0) {
     char str[20];
     int idx;
     printf("input was %s", input);
     idx = sscanf(input, "%s %d", str, &idx);
   }
```

it always prints `input was inspect` but the following space and number are not read?
What would be the right way to check if the user typed "inspect" and get the index he typed afterwards like I am trying to do?

thank you

Comment: Try not to use minuscule buffers, use a safer default like `char input[255]`. Also pass this buffer length into `scanf` if you're using that to be sure you don't overflow it by accident: `scanf("%255s", &input)`.

Comment: Thanks but when using this I still have the same issue and i had to remove the `&` in front of input to make it work.

Comment: `input` won't contain any spaces for `strtok` to find! The `%s` specifier stops scanning at the first whitespace character. Use `fgets` to input a line of text.

Comment: Sorry I am too new to this. How to use fgets to read from console?

Comment: By using `stdin` as the file stream.

Comment: There are three issues here: 1. inappropriate use of scanf() 2. inappropriate use of strtok() 3. The choice of these two functions is not the best for your task. Please specify what do you need. 1. Explanation of scanf() usage. 2. Explanation of strtok() usage. 3. A sample code that can solve your task.

Comment: Note that `idx = sscanf(input, "%s %d", str, &idx);` won't work for 2 reasons: a) you filtered off the part of the input string that contained those values and b) the value scanned into `idx` will get overwritten by the assignment `idx = sscanf(...);`

Answer (score 0):

You have few choices, and you want to choose one and not mix them up.

For reading the input, consider using the fgets. Much safer, with fewer exceptions to deal with. I've listed the equivalent sscanf, but it's much harder to use. They will both bring in a complete line to 'input'. Notice that the fgets will also include the trailing new line.

```
   // make buffer large enough.
char input[255] ;

if ( fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) != NULL ) {
   ...
}

// OR
if ( sscanf("%19[^\n]", input) = 1 ) {
} ;
```

For parsing: few options to parse the input` string.

Between the option, I would vote for the sscanf, as it provides the most validation and protection against bad input, overflow, etc. The strcmp(strtok(...)) can easily result in SEGV errors, when strtok returns NULL.

Using sscanf

```
  if ( sscanf(input, "inspect %d", &idx) ==1 ) {
     ... Show Element idx
  } ;
```

Using strtok/strcmp

```
  if ( strcmp(strtok(input, " "), "inspect") == 0 ) {
      if ( sscanf("%d", strtok(NULL, " "), &idx) == 1 ) {
          .. Show element idx
      } ;
  } ;
```

Using strtol

```
  if ( strcmp(strtok(input, " "), "inspect") == 0 ) {
      char *stptr = strtok(input, " "), *endptr = NULL ;
      idx = strtol(stptr, &endptr, 10) ;
      if ( endptr != stptr ) {
          .. Show element idx
      } ;
  } ;
```

Comment: I tried it but it seems that my variable `input` does not include the space nor the number like Weather Vane mentioned in comments above.

Comment: I've expanded on the fgets/scanf, following xdrago comments.